# Div tag throwing null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, nullreferenceexception, servercontrols

I am accessing `div` from `Code Behind` but its throwing `Null reference exception`. I took care of some small things like

- My method is not static.
- I am accessing `div` in `NeedDataSource` Event of `Telerik`'s `RadGrid`.

Look at my markup

```
     <div id="divData" runat="server">
     ---- Some static content
    </div>
    <div id="divAuth" runat="server" class="auth">
    Content
    </div>
```

And I am using it as below

```
protected void rgrdFiles_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Some Logic
                if (Session["accessCode"] == null)
                {
                    if (applyRoles == "1")
                    {
                        divAuth.Visible = true; // Error line
                        divData.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        divAuth.Visible = false;
                        divData.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Utility.IsAuthenticUser(12, Session["accessCode"].ToString()) || applyRoles == "0")
                {
                    divAuth.Visible = false;
                    divData.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    divAuth.Visible = true;
                    divData.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
}
```

When `debugger` come of `Error Line` then I see `null` when I move mouse over `divAuth`

Comment: Please post the code wherein you have assigned the `div` `divData` to `divAuth`.

Comment: Ohh.. I am really sorry :(, thank for pointing out my mistake. Actually there are two `div`'s. Updated question.

Comment: Can you delete my question as my problem is solved and I don't remember how? So I can't accept any answer and can't post mine either... :(

Answer (score 0):

divAuth is not mentioned in your HTML. ALso please make sure it is runat server and on the same page (not in master page).

i guess, you can not accesss div inside the datasource event. please hide and show your div in ItemDataBound event.

Comment: M sorry for not posting proper code, edited code. and `div` is on same page, not master.

Comment: Is your div in Grid or outside the grid ?

Comment: Try ClientIDMode property of the page or control to Static. Also try this "HtmlGenericControl footer = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControl("footer")". Also please check if any compile time error in your project or clean the solution and build again and try. Hopefully it should solve.

Comment: I will set clientIdMode but I am not getting why should I use `FindControl` though my control is directly in page. And of course, No compilation error.

Comment: i guess, you can not accesss div inside the datasource event. please hide and show your div in ItemDataBound event.